# Why can't I get the conditional probability from the joint probability by simply substituting a value of the random variable in the joint probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

For two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, why can't I get the conditional probability $f(Y|X=x)$ from the joint probability $f(X,Y)$ by simply substituting $X=x$ in the joint probability $f(X,Y)$? Alternatively [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) states "in some cases the conditional probabilities may be expressed as functions containing the unspecified value $x$ of $X$ as a parameter". In such a case how is the conditional probability different from the joint probability?

Comment: You pretty much can! The only problem is that $x \mapsto p(x,y)$ will not sum to unity, which is a requirement for a probability measure. So, you rescale to add to unity, so you consider $x \mapsto c p(x,y).$ Since this add to unity, we must have $c p_Y(y) = c \sum\limits_x p(x,y) = 1,$ so $c = 1/p_Y(y)$ and you return to the usual definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

> In such a case how is the conditional probability different from the joint probability?

The difference is the normalizing factor. In the case of discrete random variables ( with probability masses ), then for all supported values :

$$\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)={\dfrac1{\mathsf P(X=x)}\,\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)}$$

Likewise for continuous random variables with well defined pdf.

$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)={\dfrac1{f_X(x)}\,f_{X,Y}(x, y)}$$